# R using dplyr::select() in a list-column workflow

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a list of large data frames and I want to subset each one, retaining only certain columns. The names of the columns I want are contained in character vectors unique to each data frame.

One way of doing this is with a list-column workflow. I would create a data frame with a `data` list-column holding the data frames, and a `cols` list-column holding the character
vectors.

The real application of this will include a list of 24 large datasets, paired with a list of 24 unique character vecotrs. Here is a minimal example of this data structure to illustrate the problem:

```
set.seed(2346)
df <- tibble(
  col1 = sample(c(0,1), replace=T, size=10),
  col2 = sample(c(0,1), replace=T, size=10),
  col3 = sample(c(0,1), replace=T, size=10),
  col4 = sample(c(0,1), replace=T, size=10)
)

cols <- c("col1", "col3")

df_list_col <- tibble(
  data = list(df), 
  cols = list(cols)
)
```

`df_list_col` has the list-column structure, but only in a single row.

My attempted solution is to create a third list-column to hold
the subsetted data frame. Thus:

```
df_output <- df_list_col %>% 
  mutate(subset = select(.$data, !!.$cols))
```

But this returns an error:

```
#   Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `subset`.
# x `select()` doesn't handle lists.
# ℹ Input `subset` is `select(.$data, list(c("col1", "col3")))`.
```

I also tried using `purrr::map` to apply the function:

```
df_output <- df_list_col %>% 
  mutate(subset = map(.$data, ~ select(.x, !!.$cols)))
```

But that returns a similar error. In both cases, `select()` is seeing the vector of column names as a list, not as vector. And I'm stumped on how to change this behavior.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are `list` columns.   We can extract by `unlist`ing or extracting with `[[` in `select`

```
dplyr::select(df_list_col$data[[1]], unlist(df_list_col$cols))
```

Or another option with `!!!`

```
select(df_list_col$data[[1]], !!! df_list_col$cols)
```

---

Or using the `tidyverse` syntax

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df_list_col %>% 
         mutate(subset = map2(data, cols, ~ .x %>% select(all_of(.y))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  data              cols      subset           
#  <list>            <list>    <list>           
#1 <tibble [10 × 4]> <chr [2]> <tibble [10 × 2]>
```

---

Or with `pmap`

```
df_list_col %>%
     mutate(subset = pmap(cur_data(),  ~ select(..1, all_of(..2 ))))
```

Comment: Thanks as always akrun, these are great suggestions. I prefer the option with `mutate()` because its the best fit conceptually with the list-column workflow. I'll scale this up to the actual data problem and see how it works there.